# Metrics for Provisioning Transactions in IIQ

Tags: identity, sailpoint

For metrics on provisioning transactions in IIQ, we are currently reading from the table to a file which is then getting ingested to an elastic search index through a filebeat agent. Is there any other way to do it say can I instrument IIQs code with a metrics library like Micrometer if I only wanted to measure the success and error percentage of all operations (Create, Modify etc)

One way I am thinking is to do through an input JDBC plugin but I don't need logs just metrics so haven't figured out a way yet